# Is there any compiler option to enable warning for trying to do global initialization for a global objective-c instance?

Tags: objective-c, global-variables, globalization

Recently I just there's some people trying to create a global instance in the global scope in my project, like the following does:

```
UIColor* globalColor = [UIColor red];
UIFont* globalFont = [UIFont systemFontWithSize:12];

@implementation SomeView
...
@end
```

This will cause performance penalty even crash sometime when launch. And I'm trying to write a script to check this kind of fault coding behavior, however I just realized it's quite difficult to write a perfect script to check especially when the object-c code mixed with C++, the namespace will introduce more trouble. The best solution will ask for build a light weight lexer, which should be part job of the compiler, so I just wonder is there any existing compiler option can enable error or warning for this kind of scenario?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to found any compiler option to detect this, however I wrote a little category for detect unexpected global instance. Set break point on the method will indicate will the global instance was defined.
And this ApplicationEnteredMain was defined as a global BOOL was updated to "true" before the main() was called.

```
static const char* classNameToAvoid[] = {
  "UIFont",
  "UIColor",
  "NSLocale",
  "NSBundle",
  "UIScreen",
};

@interface NSObject (AppLoadingBurdenTest)

@end

@implementation NSObject (AppLoadingBurdenTest)

+ (void)load {
  [self swizzleClassMethod:@selector(initialize) withMethod:@selector(swizzledInitialize)];
}

+ (void) swizzledInitialize {
  [self swizzledInitialize];
  if (!ApplicationEnteredMain) {
    const char* currentClassName = [NSStringFromClass(self) UTF8String];
    printf("\n--------------- will initialize class <%s> before main() was called ---------------\n", currentClassName);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(classNameToAvoid) / sizeof(long); i++) {
      if (0 == strcmp(currentClassName, classNameToAvoid[i])) {
        ASSERT_NOT_REACHED();
      }
    }
  }
}

@end
```